# Mongoose returning value from aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema with the following fields: 
 
**Schema**

```
Brote {
  name:
  content:
  created:
  likes:
}
```

and I want to sum up the number of likes in every document together. I have the following query in my file: 
 
**Index.js**

```
app.get('/brotes', (req, res) => {
  Brote.aggregate( 
    { $group: { 
      _id: null, 
      total: { $sum: "$likes" } } 
    } 
  , function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
})
```

However nothing is printed to the console. When I run the command on a mongo server it works, and I get

```
{ "_id" : null, "total" : 7 }
```

which is the expected output. Can someone potentially see where I am going wrong? I am fairly new to mongoDB and web development in general so I may just be missing something obvious. Thank you!

**EDIT: SOLVED** 
Error actually had nothing to do with the query itself (which was correct), it was an issue with the URL I was using to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make an array in aggregation pipeline like aggregate([

```
Broke.aggregate([
{
  $group: { 
   _id: null, 
   total: { $sum: "$likes" } } 
  }
}
])
.then(result => {
   console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
//handle error here
});
```

Comment: Yes I have tried using the bracket syntax as well and following this exact but it doesn't seem to make a difference either...